# How to get the Months names non-alphabetically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

Please find The below fiddle there is a table there I am converting rows to columns

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7c8223ca9a517e4a959f0ecfb2c0e39d

```
A   B   C   December    February    January
100  ABC OL    100        290         200
100  DEF OL    260        360         300
200  ABC OL    500        550         600
200  DEF OL    570        680         600
```

But i am not getting months in sequence  like December,January and February how can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the month name to a date and order by that:

```
set @col_list = (select quotename([D])+','
                 from t1
                 group by d
                 order by cast(d + ' 01, 2000' as date)
                 for xml path('')
                );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1c0ed7b7d219ac71c9547f746a046020) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: But i need the format of the months like December,January and February only. Because the month values are dynamic based on financial year

Comment: @roll . . . Did you run this?  It doesn't change the format of the months.  It simply orders the columns.

Comment: Yes i did. It is displaying column names as January,February, December. But i need to display fist December,January and February